# Did the Jews burn the Temple?

Tags: tisha-bav, agada-stories-legends

[image]In Meam Loez The Story of Tisha Bav by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan, it is written that the Romans burned to Holy of Holies and then seeing this, the Jews burned the rest of the temple and all the wealthy houses in Jerusalem so the Romans couldn’t benefit from the wealth.

Is this idea that the Jews themselves burned the Temple found anywhere? Where does Meam Loez get this from? I always thought the story went that the Romans accidentally burned the Temple.

(The terrorists referred to below are the Jewish Biryonim)

Comment: Why the downvote? -_-

Comment: If the Romans got to the holy of holies, they would have gotten into the rest of the temple.


You may be thinking of two other stories:

That one of the factions of Jews looted the temple before Antiochus did in the lead up to the Hasmonean revolt.

That a Jewish faction in the AD 70 revolt burnt the stored food during the siege of Jerusalem to force the Jews to fight.

Comment: The Romans very much did not accidentally burn down the Temple

Comment: Josephus does attempt to make it seem like an accident: He describes a meeting between Titus and his generals on the eve of the destruction, where they deliberated on whether they should destroy the Temple or not. According to Josephus, Titus was against while the generals were in favor. However, in the end a soldier acted on his own and tossed a flaming torch onto the Temple. The Roman historian Tacitus also describes the meeting, but in his version the roles are reversed: Titus wanted to destroy, the generals were against. We also know from midrashim and aggadahs that Titus was in favor.

Comment: Now, one torch isn't necessarily enough to burn the entire Temple complex, unless it was doused beforehand in gasoline. Josephus's attempt to portray it as an accident (via a soldier who didn't exactly follow orders) is likely an attempt to defend the Romans in the eyes of Jewish readers. But to burn the entire Temple, or a significant part of it (some sources hint that part of it stood standing until the Bar Kochva Revolt) takes some thinking, and teamwork. In short, putting it down to simply an accident is somewhat difficult to comprehend.

Comment: @Harel13 yes that’s what I’m referring to, but very fair deduction. Regardless of that though, I’m just wondering what this quote in this book means

Answer (score 1):

Here's the original Hebrew

[image: Meam Loez]

He says it was the שרי הפריצים and הפריצים הנשארים who did this. They burned the surrounding houses in the city. Once the fire spread and destroyed the Holy of Holies, they burned the rest of the Temple, feeling that without the Holy of Holies, what further need is there for a house?

Going back a few pages it looks like he's summarizing passages from [*sefer Yosifun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josippon), which is a Hebrew compilation of the writings of the Jewish Roman Historian Josephus.

Comment: It says near the end: וגם יתר בנין ההיכל שרפו, so it seems they did burn the rest of the Temple. I haven't read the book. Is שרי פריצים here a reference to the Romans or to the rebels?

Comment: Good catch I missed that. I thought it's a reference to the dignitaries of the city.

Comment: I added the English version where I read this to the question

Comment: @CuriousYid no upvote? I answered your question.

Comment: @robev just did, but it doesn’t fully answer my question. I’d still like to know if there’s a Jewish source that expresses this idea

Comment: @CuriousYid You didn't understand my answer. I said the source is the Jewish Roman Historian Josephus.

Comment: @robev yeah but Josephus isn’t really a reliable Jewish source. I meant more like if there’s a midrash or something that mentions this idea

Comment: I would safely assume that this is the only source, if the Meam Loez tells you this is his source...